# Scala: How to match a data from one column to other columns in data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have below data and would like to match the data from ID column of df1 to df2.

df1:

```
ID    key
1     
2     
3
4
5
```

Df2:

```
first  second third  key
--------------------------
1       9       9    777
9       8       8    878
8       1      10    765
10      12      19   909
11      2       20   708
```

Code:

```
val finalDF = Df1.join(DF2.withColumnRenamed("key", "key2"), $"ID" === $"first" || $"ID" === $"second" || $"ID" === $"third","left").select($"ID", $"key2".as("key")).show(false)

val notMatchingDF = finalDF.filter($"key" === "")
val matchingDF = finalDF.except(notMatchingDF)
val columnsToCheck = DF2.columns.toSet - "key" toList

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val tempSelectedDetailsDF = DF2.select(array(columnsToCheck.map(col): _*).as("array"), col("key").as("key2"))
val arrayContains = udf((array: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String], value: String) => array.contains(value))
val finalDF = df1.join(tempSelectedDetailsDF, arrayContains($"array", $"ID"), "left")
  .select($"ID", $"key2".as("key"))
  .na.fill("")
```

I am getting the output as below,

```
ID    key
1     777
1     765
2     708     
3
4
5
```

However i am expecting as below,here the logic is from df1 we have id column  value 1 and in df2 the value 1 is matching more than once hence i am getting above output. but i should not match second occurrence when it matches in the first occurrence.

Expected output:

```
ID    key
1     777
2     708     
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > i should not match second occurrence when it matches in the first occurrence.

I would suggest you to **create a increasing id for df2 for identifying the order of matches when joined with df1 so that it would easy later on to filter in the first matches only**. For that you can benefit from `monotonically_increasing_id()`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val finalDF = Df1.join(DF2.withColumnRenamed("key", "key2").withColumn("order", monotonically_increasing_id()), $"ID" === $"first" || $"ID" === $"second" || $"ID" === $"third","left").select($"ID", $"key2".as("key").cast(StringType), $"order")
```

Then you *separate the dataframe into matching and non-matching dataframes*

```
val notMatchingDF = finalDF.filter($"key".isNull || $"key" === "")
val matchingDF = finalDF.except(notMatchingDF)
```

After that on the `matchingDF`, *generate row numbers* for each row on each *window grouped by ID and sorted by the increasing id gereated above*. Then *filter in the first matching rows*. Then *merge in the non matching dataframe* and *drop the newly created column* and *fill all nulls with empty character*

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
def windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("order")

matchingDF.withColumn("order", row_number().over(windowSpec))
  .filter($"order" === 1)
  .union(notMatchingDF)
  .drop("order")
  .na.fill("")
```

You should have your requirement fulfilled

```
+---+---+
|ID |key|
+---+---+
|1  |777|
|2  |708|
|3  |   |
|4  |   |
|5  |   |
+---+---+
```